# Retrieve latest 3 values from a large table

Tags: mysql, performance, greatest-n-per-group, query-performance

Engine MySQL 5.6.37 
I have a continuously growing table (around 10M rows) which keeps the values from devices along with a timestamp. Below is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `meterreadings` (
 `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `meterid` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
 `metervalue` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `date_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
 KEY `meterid` (`meterid`,`date_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I would like to know if one of the past 3 meter values has crossed zero (for all meter IDs). I tried to use the below query and iterate through all the device IDs using PHP, but this approach is rather slow when I have around 500 meterids to scan:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN metervalue>0 THEN 1 END) AS present 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM meterreadings 
      where meterid= ? 
      order by Id desc 
      LIMIT 3) AS a
```

Is there a better way I can get this done, preferably with one single query and no iteration?

Comment: @Akina Added version in original post

Comment: I know how to solve your problem using variables - it will be one-step full table scan. For 10M records it can be expensive... maybe it is possible to decrease the amount of records to be scanned - for example there exists some timepoint which guarantees the last 3 values for any 'meter' is above it? If so - how much records are to be scanned when use a condition `date_time > @timepoint`?

Comment: Each 'meter' inserts a value into the table every 1 minute - so essentially I should be looking at past 3 minute values per meter.

Comment: Some values can be lost... so 3 min is not a safe period... maybe 1 day? 24*60*500 = 720k records is less than 10M...

Comment: If you switch to at least MySQL 8 (or MariaDB), you can have your meterid key as follows (meterid, date_time desc).  A select using that index would immediately get the most recent entries.  Limit 3 and there you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check:

```
SELECT meterid /* , IF(SUM(metervalue>0),1,0) flag */
FROM ( SELECT t.*,
              IF(@meterid=t.meterid, 
                 @rownum:=@rownum+1, 
                 @rownum:=1+least(0,@meterid:=t.meterid)) rown 
       FROM meterreadings t, 
            (SELECT @rownum:=1, @meterid:=0) vars
       /* WHERE t.date_time > @some_date_time */
       ORDER BY meterid, date_time DESC
     ) nums
WHERE rown < 4
GROUP BY meterid
HAVING SUM(metervalue>0) > 0
```

The resultset is a list of `meterid`'s which have at least 1 positive value within last 3 values.

Commented WHERE allows to decrease the amount of records processed by setting some "start point".

If you need full list of `meterid`'s with a 'flag' of positive value existence - remove `HAVING` condition and uncomment `flag` field in the output list.

Comment: Don't fetch `t.*` if all that you will use is `meterid` and `metervalue`.